# What excel formula do I use?

Tags: excel-formula

[image: Image of sample data]

My raw data contains yes, no and NA (Column AJ:AN).

I convert them to 1 if yes, 0 if no and blank if NA (Column CG:CK).

Based on the data in columns CG:CK, how can I get Column DM to show 100% if there are no "0" (blanks and Yes only), 0.00% if there is even just one "0" in any of the 5 columns and blank if all are blanks?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use COUNTIF:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(CG2:CK2,0),0,IF(COUNTIF(CG2:CK2,1)=COLUMNS(CG2:CK2),1,""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried it before and it gives me the answer "false". I need it to show me either 100%, 0.00% or blank since I am looking for the conformance to items 1-5.

Comment: did you try my formula? or did you assume it wouldn't work?  If should only return 1 of 3 things `0`,`1`, or `""`.

Comment: Yes I did try your formula. It returned as "False".

Comment: @AAA As you can see it does not for me.

Comment: @AAA did you change the formula any, there is no way as it is typed for it to return `FALSE`.  Did you leave off the `""` on the end?

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of **nested IF** and **COUNTIF** is in the right direction, but I would rather use your data in `AJ:AN` rather than the data in `CG:CK` in the formula.

Suppose your data starts in Row 1, you can use the following formula to return either blank `""`, `1` or `0` based on the given criteria:

> show 100% if there are no "0" (blanks and Yes only), 0.00% if there is even just one "0" in any of the 5 columns and blank if all are blanks?

```
=IF(COUNTIF(AJ1:AN1,"N/A")=5,"",IF(COUNTIF(AJ1:AN1,"No")>0,0,1))
```

Change the row number to suit your case.

Then you need to change the format of the outcome to `0%;;0.00%` through custom format, so it will show `100%` without decimal places and `0.00%` with two decimal places (if this is exactly what you want).

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

In cell `DM2` enter this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(CG2:CK2,0)>0,0,
IF(SUM(CG2:CK2)>0,1,TEXT(,)))
```

and apply this `numberformat`:

```
0%;0%;0.00%;@
```

suggest also to change the formulas in `CG2:CK2` to something like:

```
=IF(AJ2="Yes",1,IF(AJ2="No",0,TEXT(,)))
```

in order to eliminate the redundancy of `IF(AJ2="N/A","","")` in the formula

```
=IF(AJ2="Yes",1,IF(AJ2="No",0,IF(AJ2="N/A","","")))
```